# YouTube Members API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Through my code I have to see the subscriptions (members) of a YouTube channel I created the oauth system and set https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator as purposes

but when I make the request to
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/members

putting the same access token obtained from oauth gives me this error

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
                "domain": "youtube.common",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have set the parms like this

```
filter = subscriber
channelId = mychannelid
```

I expect the list of members of the oauth token YouTube channel to return to me.